# Mostrar resultados de una categoría, con tres tablas relacionadas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Buenas estoy trabajando en un blog en el que itero unas categorías en unos botones del siguiente modo:

```
@foreach ($categorias as $item)
   <a href="{{ route('app.verCategory', ['slug' => $item->slug])}}">{{ $item->valor }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Mi ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}', "web@verCategory")->name('app.verCategory');
```

Y en mi controlador lo siguiente:

```
public function verCategory($slug)
    {
        $noticias = categoryBlog::where('slug', $slug)->with('articles')->first();
        //dd($noticias);
        return view("verCategory")->with(['noticia' => $noticias]);
    }
```

**Mi tabla `articles`**

| id | titulo | foto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nombre noticia 1 | foto.jpg |
| 2 | nombre noticia 2 | foto.jpg |

**Mi tabla `category_blogs`**

| id | valor | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nutrition | nutrition |
| 2 | Training | training |

**Mi tabla `enlaza_categorias`**

| id | id_category | id_article |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

**Modelo `articles`**

```
protected $table = 'articles';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function categoriasBlogs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(categoryBlog::class, 'enlaza_categorias', 'id_article', 'id_category');
    }
```

**Modelo `categoryBlog`**

```
protected $table = 'category_blogs';
protected $primaryKey='id';

public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(articles::class, 'enlaza_categorias', 'id_category', 'id_article');
}
```

He probado con esto que pongo arriba `Route::get('/category/{slug}', "web@verCategory")->name('app.verCategory');` y a través de las relaciones parece que si me lo saca bien, pero claro necesito hacer dos iteraciones desde la tabla `articles` y como consulto desde la `category_blogs` no se como puedo hacerlas, pero al final necesito algo como esto pero que solo saque los articulos que están con esa categoría:

```
$noticias = articles::where('destacado', 0)->where('estado', 1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->with('categoriasBlogs')->paginate(8);
$destacadas = articles::where('destacado', 1)->where('estado', 1)->with('categoriasBlogs')->get();
```

Gracias!

**Edición**
Estoy haciendo con `join` y me sale bien, pero no si hay modo de hacerlo con las relaciones.

```
$destacadas = articles::join('enlaza_categorias', 'articles.id', '=', 'enlaza_categorias.id_article')
                    ->where('enlaza_categorias.id_category', $catMarcada->id)->where('articles.destacado', 1)->where('estado', 1)->with('categoriasBlogs')
                    ->select('articles.*', 'enlaza_categorias.id_article','enlaza_categorias.id_category')
                    ->get();
$noticias = articles::join('enlaza_categorias', 'articles.id', '=', 'enlaza_categorias.id_article')
                    ->where('enlaza_categorias.id_category', $catMarcada->id)->where('articles.destacado', 0)->where('estado', 1)->with('categoriasBlogs')
                    ->select('articles.*', 'enlaza_categorias.id_article','enlaza_categorias.id_category')
                    ->paginate(8);
```

Comment: No sé si entiendo bien la pregunta, pero puedes [restringir el eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) . Por ejemplo `$noticias = categoryBlog::where('slug', $slug)->with(['articles' => function ($query) { $query->where('destacado', 0)->where('estado', 1); }])->first();`

Comment: He editado mi pregunta @porloscerrosΨ al final hay una solución por si lo entiendes mejor, gracias

Comment: Si lo que te interesa son los artículos y no necesariamente la catagoría con los artículos, también puedes [consultar la existencia de la relación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). Algo así: `$noticias = articles::whereHas('categoriasBlogs', function ($query) use ($slug) { $query->where('slug', $slug); })->where('destacado', 0)->where('estado', 1)->get();`